# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when trying to locally call to API

Tags: http, ssl, https, certificate, protocols

I have an AngularJS served at http://localhost:4200 and an Apache server api located at https://localhost. Both of these separately work just fine.

But when trying to request from my AngularJS app which is sitting in a non-SSL protocol and on a different port to my API sitting on SSL protocol and on a different port, I get this error `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` on my Chrome devTools network tab.

Do I need to change my SSL configuration? Should I enable or disable an option in Chrome? Should I add a SSL certificate?

Answer (score 43):

The problem was resolved by going straight to the SSL endpoint, then chrome alerts that this resource is not secured. Clicking on "Proceed" will resolve the problem when trying to request for that resource again.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, I had a frontend and backend, I did need to accept at browser the certificate on back before start to work at front. You saved my day.

Comment: Life Saved! Thanks! Spent 2 hours thinking i was making a mistake making my ssl certificates.

Comment: Very useful :D:D

Comment: you are a hero.

Comment: Is there a solution that configures the SSL certification?
Is it responsibility of frontend or backend?

Comment: Works! Very useful for testing front/back end using internal ip and self signed certificates!

Comment: This worked for me after hours of fiddling with caches, chrome settings, backend and frontend auth configs. (Also for an AngularJS app). Please mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Although subjective sometimes it can be your security team doing this.

In my case it was our organizations opendns security blocking me as it thought what i was doing was suspicious.