# How to call POST method in javascript onclick button in oracle apex

Tags: web-services, post, oracle-apex

I want to know how can i call POST web service method using javascript, when i click on button in ORACLE APEX.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "your_url";
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",  url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //do whatever you want to do
        } else {
            //do whatever you want to do
        }
    }
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        "key_1": "value_1",
        "key_2": "value_2"
    }));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Arif,
Thank you for reply. I applied your code, but i still having errors. You can see demo on apex.oracle.com with this credentials:
Workspace: ws_formation
Username: asoukaina
Password: s@boulah123
I used the Application 146790 - PP SIGN , 146790:1

Comment: I logged in to apex, but that definitely won't work on my side, as you are using localhost in code. Although you can try debugging using Console. After running the page press F12, then press on CallWS button, and see what message/errors are being displayed.

Comment: I get this error message:
https://localhost.oracle.com:8888/api/signature/ net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, even if it works when im using Postman to test (But with the modification at the Settings level; i set SSL Certificate Verification = OFF)

Comment: Got through [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737370/neterr-cert-authority-invalid-when-trying-to-locally-call-to-api)   [link_2](https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome) Or, copy paste the url in browser, an error will be shown, click advanced --> proceed. Now retry doing through Apex. I am also not sure which will be the right approach.