# Angular default app ng serve: privacy error in Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ssl, https, localhost

I'm trying to follow this guide https://angular.io/guide/setup-local. I installed node.js and angular cli and build default app:

```
ng new my-app
```

Now i want to start app:

```
cd my-app
ng serve --open
```

It starts ok:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But when i open page in Chrome it is [privacy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSvLi.png)

When i tried to open it in Firefox it all work great.
I tried to start app with next command:

```
 ng serve --open --ssl true
```

Still the same error.
Any help? At this point i don't need https, i just want to be able to open my app in Chrome.

+

I posted wrong error code. I get this: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open your website using SSL protocol (by using `https://` or port `:443`. Could you give us the URL you are using to access to your application ?

Comment: why do you try to use --ssl option? is it required for something? just skip it. for local development usually just http is enough

Comment: This worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/71604341/2093371

Answer (score 29, accepted):

open `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`, enable this flag and restart chrome. Chrome will then ignore wrong certificates for localhost

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
Need to use SSL, though: `ng serve --open --ssl true`

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767886/998605), you can also go directly to the SSL endpoint in Chrome and click **Proceed** under the Advance button. This procedure solved the issue of NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID for me.

Answer (score -1):

You just open [`http://localhost:4200`](http://localhost:4200) but not `https://`.

[image]

Comment: You can force `https` when you click **Advanced** button. Tick the option and continue to access `https://localhost:4200`.

Comment: http redirects me to https